# Pandas.to_csv gives error 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save a panda dataframe to csv and it fails with error:

```
df.to_csv(location, sep='|', index=False, header=True)
```

'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

I have pandas version as:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.19.2'
>>>
```

On Another machine, same commands works. Version of pandas installed is 0.18.1

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.18.1'
>>>
```

I understand adding encoding='utf-8' will get me through the error. 
However I was wondering if there was recent change that caused later version of pandas to fail.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.18.1/pandas/core/frame.py
we find :

```
formatter = fmt.CSVFormatter(self, path_or_buf,
                                     line_terminator      = line_terminator,
                                     sep                  = sep,
                                     encoding             = encoding,
                                     compression          = compression,
                                     quoting              = quoting,
                                     na_rep               = na_rep,
                                     float_format         = float_format,
                                     cols                 = columns,
                                     header               = header,
                                     index                = index,
                                     index_label          = index_label,
                                     mode                 = mode,
                                     chunksize            = chunksize,
                                     quotechar            = quotechar,
                                     engine               = kwds.get("engine"),
                                     tupleize_cols        = tupleize_cols,
                                     date_format          = date_format,
                                     doublequote          = doublequote,
                                     escapechar           = escapechar,
                                     decimal              = decimal     )
```

from we find : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/frame.py

```
formatter = fmt.CSVFormatter(self,  path_or_buf,
                                    line_terminator =line_terminator,
                                    sep             =sep,
                                    encoding        =encoding,
                                    compression     =compression,
                                    quoting         =quoting,
                                    na_rep          =na_rep,
                                    float_format    =float_format,
                                    cols            =columns,
                                    header          =header,
                                    index           =index,
                                    index_label     =index_label,
                                    mode            =mode,
                                    chunksize       =chunksize,
                                    quotechar       =quotechar,
                                    
                                    tupleize_cols   =tupleize_cols,
                                    date_format     =date_format,
                                    doublequote     =doublequote,
                                    escapechar      =escapechar,
                                    decimal         =decimal)
```

The only difference is the "engine" parameter... We should now dig deeper on this "engine" parameter :-(
somewhere here : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.18.1/pandas/formats/format.py

and here :
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/formats/format.py

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your answer and helpful links.  I upgraded to most recent version and everything is good.